# XmlReader Read() Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, stream

Im trying to read a xml file with xmlreader, here is my code:

```
public XmlReader LoadXMLToReader(string inputXMLPathFile)
{
    byte[] xmlData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputXMLPathFile);
    MemoryStream xmlStream = new MemoryStream(xmlData);
    xmlStream.Position = 0;

    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(xmlStream);
    reader.Read();
    return reader;
}
```

That function give me a error on `reader.read()` of "data at the root level is invalid. Line 1 position 1" and I read about the BOM, so how can I fix this function to prevent that BOM?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Columns>
  <Column>1</Column>
  <Column>2</Column>
  <Column>3</Column>
</Columns>
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: What is the structure of the xml file you are trying to load? Can you update your question with that too please?

Comment: Why would you do this? Just try `XmlReader.Create(new StreamReader(inputXMLPathFile))`. And why should you do the first `Read`? Let your caller do that.

Comment: This not resolve my exception...

Comment: @JohnSaunders why not just `XmlReader.Create(inputXMLPathFile)`?

Comment: Because I forgot about that overload?

Comment: @user1977936 if you read the BOM what encoding it says it is? Can it be that the econding says it is not UTF-8 and you are trying to read it as UTF-8? Is the content really UTF-8?

Comment: What exactly is in `inputXMLPathFile`? Is it a path to a file, or does it contain XML?

Comment: is a path to a file, @Pawel is utf-8 really..

Comment: If `inputXMLPathFile` contains the path to the XML file, that is what is causing the exception.  I don't think `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes()` does what you think it does.  The way you have it right now, you're trying to parse the file path as XML, not the actual _contents_ of the file.

Comment: @jwnace, but path exists and is rigth

Comment: Take another look at John's suggestion above.  I think that's on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is at this line of code:

```
byte[] xmlData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputXMLPathFile);
```

You are passing a *file name* to a function which returns a binary representation of a string — of the actual string passed to that function, not, somehow magically, of a file referred to a path which is conincidetally passed in as a string value.

There are many options how to simplify your method. One of them is this:

```
public XmlReader LoadXMLToReader(string inputXMLPathFile)
{
    return XmlReader.Create(File.Open(inputXMLPathFile, FileMode.Read));
}
```